# How does Cocoa compare to Microsoft, Qt?

Tags: wpf, cocoa, qt, programming-languages, comparison

I have done a few months of development with Qt (built GUI programmatically only) and am now starting to work with Cocoa. I have to say, I *love* Cocoa. A lot of the things that seemed hard in Qt are easy with Cocoa. Obj-C seems to be far less complex than C++.

This is probably just me, so: Ho do you feel about this?

How does Cocoa compare to WPF (is that the right framework?) to Qt?
How does Obj-C compare to C# to C++?
How does XCode/Interface Builder compare to Visual Studio to Qt Creator?
How do the Documentations compare?

For example, I find Cocoa's Outlets/Actions far more useful than Qt's Signals and Slots because they actually seem to cover most GUI interactions while I had to work around Signals/Slots half the time. (Did I just use them wrong?)
Also, the standard templates of XCode give me copy/paste, undo/redo, save/open and a lot of other stuff practically for free while these were rather complex tasks in Qt.

Please only answer if you have actual knowledge of at least two of these development environments/frameworks/languages.

Comment: If you had to "work around" Qt's signals/slots half of the time for UI actions, then you were probably using them incorrectly or using the incorrect ones.  I've found them to be approximately on-par with the outlets/actions in the little I've done with Cocoa.

Comment: What did you do eventually? Do you have a preference between WPF and QT?

Comment: @YonatanNir i never actually used WPF in the end. I have done a fair deal of Qt and Cocoa though. Really, for me it comes down to the choice of programming language. Qt in C++ is kind of bad because C++ is kind of bad. Cocoa in Obj-C is markedly nicer to work with than C++ in my opinion. I found the PyQt bindings for Qt to be excellent and a real alternative to native C++/Qt. The final thing is QML though. QML is a new scripting layer in Qt, which is just amazing and blows both C++/Obj-C and Python clear out of the water. Qt and QML, with a minimal C++ or Python backend is the way to go, IMHO.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I have worked with Cocoa / Obj-C on and off over the years.  As of 2010 I find it quite limiting compared to WPF / NET Framework.  I will list some of the differences I've found, and you can judge for yourself.

**Markup language**

When I design in WPF I get markup that is very simple XML that I can easily hand-edit or edit using tools I write myself.  In Cocoa I must use xib files, which are not designed for easy hand-editing or manipulation.  Here is a simple example of WPF markup:

```
<DockPanel>
  <Label>Select your favorite food:</Label>
  <ComboBox
    SelectedText="{Binding FavoriteFood}"
    SelectedItemsSource="{Binding AllFoods}" />
</DockPanel>
```

This is the entire markup, and is equivalent to about 50 lines of hard-to-edit .xib.

The ability to see and edit simple XAML is incredibly valuable for:

- Direct manual editing
- Communication with peers (eg StackOverflow)
- Source contrrol
- Searching
- Automated transformations

**Layout capabilities**

In WPF I can use panels to automatically lay out my controls as the window size changes.  I can use styles to define the spacing between my controls, or I can adjust margins to get the precise look I want, or both.  In either case my UI will automatically adjust to changes in font sizes, window size, and screen resolution.  In Cocoa, all controls are at specific x and y locations as with WinForms and the only thing I can do is auto-resize.  This is extremely limiting.  For example:

- Controls cannot wrap around to a new row or column as the window gets smaller (WrapPanel)
- Controls cannot add/remove detail based on available space
- Controls cannot move around to make room for a control that has more text than was originally expected
- Controls cannot selectively shrink or enlarge to fill available space
- Interface Builder initially sets controls to comply with interface guidelines, but a applying new style cannot change layout.

The advantage of WPF layout is that you can express your *intent* via the way you add controls to panels, then adjust the precise layout later.  Note that WPF can also work the old-fashioned way but once you've used panels for layout you'll never go back to X/Y layout.

For example, one application I did had rows containing star ratings plus comment boxes.  Normally the row was only the height of a star rating, but when long commments were typed in the text box the TextBox got taller which made the row taller, so the following rows moved down.  With WPF I got this behavior for free - with Cocoa I would have had to hand-code it.

**Data connectivity**

With Cocoa / Obj-C you are pretty much limited to the built-in data connectivity, which includes basic database access and serialization to and from files.  With WPF / NET Framework you can directly bind your UI to practically anything under the sun, including:

- Relational databases (SQL, Oracle, etc)
- Object databases (Objectivity, Versant, etc)
- Legacy databases (Access, dBase, R:Base, etc)
- COBOL databases on mainframes
- Proprietary database formats (hundreds)
- Web pages
- Web services (SOAP, REST, etc)
- XML files
- Flat files (comma-delmited, tab delimited, fixed width)
- Office documents (Word, Excel, etc)
- OpenOffice documents
- PDF form fields
- GPS receiver data (current location)
- Positions of physical switches, buttons, levers, knobs, sliders, etc
- Time (local or network)
- Performance counters (CPU utilization, etc)
- Cameras (Video cameras, web cams, still image cameras, etc)
- Analog electronic inputs
- MIDI (musical instrument keyboards, pickups, etc)
- OBD-II (vehicle monitoring)
- LDAP and Active Directory (user account information)
- WBEM and SNMP (network device status and configuration)

In fact, you can bind to practically anything that has had a driver written in any NET Framework language - and there are over a hundred NET Framework languages.

**Repetitive code**

In Cocoa your model consists of a .h and a .m file, your controller consists of a .h and a .m file, and your view consists of a .xib file.  Every single field in every object in your model must be referenced every one of these places!

In WPF / NET, a single field generally only appears in two lines of code:  Once where the model is defined, and once where it is presented by the view.  For example, in my code I usually define simple model fields in XML:

```
<Property Name="City" Type="string" />
```

then to create a text box to edit the city I simply drag the "City" property into my view and end up with this XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding City}" />
```

So "City" is mentioned in only two lines of code in my entire application (unless I have another "City" text box elsewhere).  In Cocoa "City" will be referenced at least five times.

**Binding directly to the model**

In Cocoa a single controller is really only suitable for a single view:  If you create a new view for the same model you need a new controller.  In WPF / NET there is a better way to do it, though you can still create controllers if you *really* want to.

In WPF / NET a view will typically bind most of its controls directly to the model (see my City example above).  Other controls will be bound to a "View Model" that models the state information associated with the current view.  For example, if you are searching the "View Model" would contain the search string so it can be used by the view both to filter the results and to hilight the search text.

In WPF / NET you can also bind multiple properties of a control to the same or different parts of your model (or view model):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AmountToTransfer}"
         Background="{edf:Binding UserIsHappy ? Green : White}" />
```

The difference is that in WPF a view model is usually shareable between several screens that are similar in their behavior, so in a LOB application when you create a custom view all you need to do is edit a single file.

**Command architecture**

In Cocoa a button stores its target and action in a `NSActionCell` within the view, which means that it will invoke a specific method on a specific object (typically the controller).  In WPF / NET a button has a Click event that works the same way, but it also has a Command property that allows you to invoke a command.

Commands in WPF are very powerful, since a single Command may be shared throughout the application.  For example, WPF itself defines a Delete command.  As long as your model responds to this command, adding a "Delete" button to your view is as simple as selecting the Delete command in the properties window, which creates this XAML:

```
<Button Command="Delete" />
```

This is all you have to do to get a functional delete button that deletes the object from a list.  Note the built-in Delete command also:

- Has a key binding to the Delete key on the keyboard
- Supplies language-appropriate text ("Delete" or "Eliminar" or "Löschen" or "Supprimer" or ...)
- Includes a descriptive tool tip

A command is routed to ancestor objects and models, so in a typical application you almost never need to specify which object receives the command.

**Style sheets**

In Cocoa there is no mechanism to apply style sheets to panels and have them affect all the controls in the panel, either at design time or at run time.  For example an application may want to:

- Make all the TextBoxes in a given area read-only
- Make all labels bold
- Give all ComboBoxes a light green background
- Add uniform spacing between a set of buttons
- Use a large green checkmark for a set of checkboxes
- Add a Delete button to all lists
- Make all Delete buttons appear as a red "brushed" X instead of as a traditional button
- Make the same settings on several separate items

WPF / NET makes all of these operations trivial through the use of styles.  You can set any property of any object through a style.  Styles can be set implicitly by object type or explicitly, for example:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" />
```

Style sheets can be defined anywhere you like:  in a control libraries, at the application level, specific to a "theme", on a window, in a specific control's resource dicitionary, or directly on a control.

**Control templates**

In Cocoa you cannot do much to change the visual styling of controls except to subclass them, since they each draw their own appearance.  In WPF / NET the appearance of a control is given by its template which can be freely replaced with pretty much anything you can think of.

For example:

- You can use a ListBox in your drop-down menus and style it to look like regular menu items (with a checkbox beside the currently-selected item)
- You can change a TreeView to appear as a sequence of ListBoxes instead of a tree
- You can change a slider's "thumb" to appear as a business symbol or cartoon character depending on your target audience (slide a light bulb or Mickey Mouse back and forth)
- You can change a slider to appear as a knob or to follow a non-linear path
- You can change a CheckBox to appear as a click on / click off button, a lock icon that opens and closes, or a door that opens and shuts

Control templates and data templates may also include built-in animations, so for example your door can actually animate swinging open and closed when you click on it.  This is trivially simple to do in Expression Blend:  It takes about 20 clicks of the mouse.  Just create two linear animations and attach them to event triggers.

**Custom controls**

Cocoa and WPF both allow you to subclass existing controls to create new ones.  In Cocoa the new controls are serialized to the .xib / .nib file.  In WPF they are part of the XAML just like the built-in controls:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock>
    Hello, <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}" />.
    <Bold>Good morning!</Bold>  How are you today?
  </TextBlock>
  <my:JoySelector Happiness="{Binding Happiness}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In this example JoySelector would be a control I defined and Happiness would be one of its properties.

A big difference between Cocoa and WPF is in the drawing of the custom controls.  In Cocoa you must code calls to drawing primitives to create your control's appearance.  While this is an option in WPF, it is usually much more easily done using a control template.

For example, in Cocoa you might write:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(30, 20);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

whereas in WPF using XAML the equivalent would be:

```
<Ellipse Width="30" Height="20" Fill="Red" />
```

or in WPF in code (C#):

```
return new Ellipse { Width=30, Height=30, Fill=Brushes.Red };
```

A ControlTemplate may of course have multiple items:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="my:JoySelector">
  <Grid Width="50" Height="50">
    <Ellipse Width="30" Height="20" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Left" />
    <Path Data="M0,0 L3,5 L8,8 L5,3 L0,0" Fill="Blue" />
    <ComboBox
      SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding Happiness}"
      Style="{StaticResource JoySelectorBoxStyle}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This XAML would typically be created in Expression Blend by right-clicking a JoySelector, selecting Edit > Template > Create New, drawing the Ellipse, Path, and ComboBox using the drawing tools, and selecting the ComboBox binding and style from the Properties window.

**Data templates**

In Cocoa if you want a list or tree of items of various types, such as an equipment inventory in a game or a  list of various types of accounts (investment, money market, savings), you pretty much have to code it all yourself.  In WPF / NET you can use DataTemplates.

For example, if every weapon has a "hit strength" and a "defense strength" you might include a data template like this:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="game:Weapon">
  <DockPanel TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource WeaponDrawing}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeaponName}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HitStrength}" Foreground="Red" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binidng DefenseStrength}" Foreground="Blue" />
  </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Other game objects would use different templates, then the inventory could be displayed using a ListBox using a WrapPanel to lay them out in reading order.  (Note that in WPF, a ListBox doesn't have to present its items in a vertical list:  Any panel can be used.)

This same technique is important in LOB applications:  For example, you can have a default representation for an Invoice that is set in an application-wide DataTemplate, so any part of your application that presents lists of Invoices will automatically display them in the default format.  This might include an icon, the invoice number, a tooltip popup with additional information, and a context menu that allows the invoice to be opened and/or edited.

**Triggers and animations**

In Cocoa you can do animations, but must write code both to create the animation and to apply the animation.  In WPF you can define the animation using a timeline in Expression Blend, and set EventTriggers and PropertyTriggers in the view to control when it runs.  To create an animation that shakes a button, just right-click to create a timeline, set the button's position, rotation or scale using the mouse at a few points on the time line, and change the automatically-created EventTrigger to the event you want to trigger the button.

Cocoa has no animation property store or coercion mechanism, so any changes made by the animation are permanent:  You can't remove the animation and have the property values revert.  Also you cannot animate properties of shared resources (such as brush colors) without manually copying them, and you can't animate to out-of-range values and have the control itself coerce to the appropriate value.  In WPF the animation system has the ability to keep track of animation values, bound values, default values and coerced values separately so you don't run into these problems.

In WPF you can set animations to run on UI events like button clicks, property state changes (including data changes in the model), events generated by the model, to run continuously, or via code.

In WPF you can create custom animation classes and use these with Expression Blend as if they were part of WPF.  You can also draw the Geometry objects used by the built-in PathAnimation rather than coding it yourself.

Note that WPF has the ability to construct and start animations in code if you really want to.  Also note that embedding an animation from a separate application such as Quartz Composer, is not the same thing as animating properties of UI objects.  Both Cocoa and WPF can embed animations created with other technologies but with WPF you can use Expression Blend to create a timeline that animates any part of your UI.

**Conversions as part of binding**

Cocoa has the ability to do conversions to and from from a single value using a NSFormatter.  Anything more complicated must be done in the controller.  In WPF you can use a StringFormat for the simple cases Cocoa's built-in NSFormatters cover, but you can also specify an IValueConverter or IMultiValueConverter to implement custom conversion of values.  For example, you can add a custom converter to a bar chart data series to cause the data items in the bar chart to animate to their target values in rapid sequence (known as a "jelly" animation).  WPF's converters can be used one-way or two-way and can convert a single value or multiple values.

Conversions also allow you to bind to multiple properties or calculations and to format the result, for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{edf:Binding (Height + Width)/2, StringFormat=0.000}" />
```

This sort of binding with conversion is not possible in Cocoa.

**Third party controls**

In Cocoa you can generally only include UI widgets designed for Cocoa in your application.  In WPF you can include WPF controls but you can also include sections of your UI developed using WinForms, MFC, HTML, Java, Flash, and other technologies.  WPF provides facilities for integrating these other technologies directly into WPF, even to the extent of using its markup system to construct the objects and set their properties, for example:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock>Here is a WinForms control:</TextBlock>
  <WindowsFormsHost>
    <tools:LegacyChartingControl
      Width="20" Height="30"
      Title="Graph of something"
      SeriesXMin="0"
      SeriesXMax="10" ... />
  </WindowsFormsHost>
</StackPanel>
```

**Externally-created media**

Both Cocoa and WPF can include media such as videos, animations, and bitmaps that have been created in third-party tools.  Each environment supports all such media types supported by the underlying operating system.  WPF provides a bit more than Cocoa in terms of controlling the media, for example you if you set a button's command to "MediaCommands.NextTrack" or "MediaCommands.FastForward", the media will automatically respond appropriately.  Also, WPF provides some improvements in the asynchronous loading of media.

WPF (through Silverlight) also supports several high quality video and audio codecs in a fully cross-platform manner so you can rely on your media working on any platform.

There are also tools that allow you to convert drawings created in tools like Illustrator or animations created in tools like Flash into native WPF drawings and animations, allowing you to manipulate and data-bind their properties.  For example, you could take a bouncing ball animation created in Flash and data-bind its Y coordinate at apogee so that the ball bounces higher or lower based on the data value in your model.

**Garbage collection**

As of 2007 garbage collection is finally supported in Cocoa / Obj-C, but many libraries still can't handle it so most of the Cocoa code being written today is still using manual memory allocation with reference counting.  Thus even today you still a lot of "[abc release]" sprinkled throughout Cocoa code!  WPF / NET has had garbage collection from day one, so it does not have this problem.

**Execution within web browser**

Cocoa applications are currently limited to executing as desktop applications, whereas WPF can run just as easily within the web browser as on the desktop, using either XBAP or Silverlight technology.

**Cross-platform capability**

The story here is similar:

- Cocoa applications run natively on Mac OS X, and can also run on Windows and Linux by using Cocotron or GNUstep and restricting yourself to a subset of the features.
- WPF applications run natively on Windows, and can also run on Mac OS X and Linux by using Silverlight and restricting yourself to a subset of the features.

The only significant difference is that Silverlight can run in the browser and has much better vendor support and tooling than Cocotron or GNUstep.

**Other advanced capabilities of WPF**

So far I have not found any capability in Cocoa that is not also in WPF / NET, but I have found many in WPF / NET that are not in Cocoa, for example:

- All controls such as buttons, textboxes, comboboxes, etc can operate just as well within 3D scenes as within 2D layouts.  They can also be arbitrarily stretched, rotated, skewed, etc.
- Advanced drawing capabilities such as PolyBeziers, combined geometries, RenderTransform vs LayoutTransform, alpha transparency control, etc
- Advanced brushes such as gradient brushes, tiled image brushes, and "Visual brushes" which allow you to create an arbitrarily complex brush for painting, for example you can paint a reflection of your window including all its controls.
- Animation subsystem allows practically every property to be animated, for example I animated a TextBox's "Text" property to make it appear that text was being typed in

**Third party algorithms and drivers**

Cocoa / Obj-C can call pre-compiled libraries that use C calling conventions and call invoke methods on objects defined in certain other languages.  This means that a C-style API is generally required for third-party code that needs to be integrated into your application.  WPF / NET can include code written in over 100 languages directly into your application and allows you to access all functionality directly.  In addition, it can also call into precompiled code written in other languages using C, C++, COM, DCOM, Web Services, and other calling conventions.  In addition, there are open-source shims allowing NET Framework code to call directly into a wide variety of other languages and systems.  This means that WPF applications almost never have to include more than a tiny amount of glue code to connect to third party code, including device drivers.

**Language comparison**

Comparing Objective-C with C# is a major task, and one I will not attempt.  Suffice it to say that as of version 4.0, C# contains all the features on Objective-C and many, many, many more.  I learned Objective-C in 1989 - a long time before C# was even conceived of - and at the time it was an amazingly powerful language.  Now when I use it I cringe, especially at the loss of LINQ and Generics.

Try this sort of data transformation in Objective-C:

```
DataContext =
  from lesson in AllLessons
  where lesson.Active
  groupby lesson.Category into category
  select new
  {
    categoryName = category.Key.Name,
    lessonsInCategory =
      from lesson in category
      select new
      {
        lesson,
        fullName = lesson.ShortName + " " + lesson.Suffix,
        priority = rand.Next(10)
      }
  };
```

If AllLessons is provided dynamically, you can directly bind this result in WPF (with `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />`) and have it dynamically update in real time.

When using LINQ with C# you can also do joins, sorting, etc.  There is no back-end code to write at all, and Visual Studio's IntelliSense helps you complete the names of properties, etc as you edit and even underlines your mistakes.

I don't know of any good comparison between Objective-C and C#, but there is a good comparison between C# and Java on wikipedia that calls out many of C#'s features that are also missing from Objective-C.

**Language bindings**

Cocoa is not restricted to Objective-C, and WPF is not restricted to C#.  Both are accessible from a number of other languages.  The difference is that Cocoa is built around Objective-C so that using it from another language can become quite awkward.  For example, actions become an Objective-C method call which has very different semantics than Java or other languages.  On the other hand, WPF was intentionally designed to not require any special C# features so it could be easily used from other languages.  For example, when used with Java (which is lacking true properties), the PropertyDescriptor uses get and set methods instead.

In addition, because it is built on the NET Framework, a WPF application can simultaneously work against objects and libraries coded in multiple languages.  This means that if you find a great C++, Haskell or Ruby implementation of an algorithm you can simply use the code without rewriting it into your language of choice.  With Cocoa you generally have to rewrite the code as Objective-C or create shim code to call the other language.

**Common advantages**

Here are several advantages of Cocoa over its competitors that it shares with WPF:

- Rich typography functionality
- Ability to include 3D graphics
- Built in rich text editing including spell checking
- Undo/redo
- Adding functionality to existing classes (categories in Obj-C, attached properties and styles in WPF)
- Easy remoting of method calls

**Final notes**

When comparing Cocoa to WPF, you should compare Interface Builder with Expression Blend, not with Visual Studio.  Visual Studio is fine for writing code, but in my opinion, Expression Blend is the *only* tool for designing the user interface.

For practical application developement, the main difference between WPF and Cocoa is generally *not* the more powerful graphics abilities of WPF, since these can be included in a Cocoa application by hand-coding them.  The main difference is the data binding and the evolution from model-view-controller to model-view-viewmodel that makes WPF so much more efficient for actually developing applications.

I may have missed a recent Cocoa improvement in the above description since I have not used Cocoa very much recently.  If I have been unfair to Cocoa (or to WPF for that matter) in any way, please add a comment and let me know what I missed.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This is awesome!  
Just two notes: (1) Layouts in Cocoa can easily be set to autoresize with a window or box. (2) Conversions can be included in Cocoa using subclasses of NSFormatter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have updated both the "Layout capabilties" and "Conversions as part of binding" sections of my answer based on your comments.  Enjoy!

Comment: By the way, Cocoa's autoresize feature doesn't even hold a candle to the powerful layout capabilities of WPF.  The lack of real layout capability in Cocoa is in my opinion one of its biggest drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, even though I don't need any advanced layouting capabilities in my application, I can see how limiting Cocoa is in this regard (and I can see this reflected in nearly every OSX applications out there). After reading your text, I am eager to try WPF some time!

Comment: One thing keeps to itch me, though: In quite a few cases, Cocoa/Interface Builder is limiting for the reason of observing rules in the Apple Human Interface Guidelines. Custom styles and custom controls  for example are thoroughly discouraged in the HIG and thus hard to implement in Cocoa (custom views are permitted). This probably is the reason why OSX looks far more consistent than Windows. Still, as far as the capabilities of the frameworks go, this is a disadvantage of course.

Comment: I haven't read through the whole thing, but whatever I've read so far (about half of it) seems really accurate and insightful for me. +1

Comment: I've found your comments on WPF very insightful as my background is mainly web development and I do have some Cocoa experience. However, there are a lot of things you mention about Cocoa that are horribly wrong, even with my relatively lower level of experience. For example, you mention using 5 lines of code to access a property from a view. Using proper Cocoa bindings, I would likely only need the same two lines of code (maybe 3). Declaring the property in the .h file, synthesizing it in the .m, and then binding it to an NSObjectController in Interface Builder.

Comment: Additional notes: while more limited than WPF, Cocoa isn't as limited as you state on layout; Cocoa/Obj-C includes CoreData which bridges into a relational SQL database if you want; Cocoa doesn't require every field in every object to be referenced in three places, you'll need .h and .m for public properties but private properties can go in the .m only — public properties can be referenced but are never declared in a .xib; Cocoa's key-value coding mechanisms can do conversions to an extent, but that misses the point that in Obj-C duck typing is a fundamental feature; ...

Comment: ... ARC is the answer to garbage collection; Silverlight isn't available for Linux other than via a third party workalike that lags the real releases; everything you list as "other advanced capabilities of WPF" is available on Cocoa via CoreAnimation (for 2d and 3d transforms) and Quartz (for PDF equivalent drawing abilities); Obj-C can link to and call any language supported by GCC or LLVM.

Comment: Outstanding explanation. You've put into words what I've experienced, but could never explain as well.

Comment: After using .NET for a couple projects, I feel similar about C# and .NET.  Having worked in Objective C (and hating it), I found C# to be much more intuitive.  Coming from a web background, XAML made a lot more sense than unclear, tightly-coupled XML in ``.xib`` files.  I recently tried spacing out the tabs, removing size constraints, as I would do in XAML in my ``xib`` file, and to my surprise, XCode set fixed **point-based**, absolutely-positioned coordinates on every object I removed them from.  XCode also removed all tab characters... and I happen to **love** tab characters.

Answer (score 3):

WPF is the UI part of the .NET framework so if you're only comparing the UI parts then you could say it's the right framework. Qt and Cocoa provide a lot more (sockets, threading etc) than WPF (but those things are covered in other parts of the .NET framework).

Obj-C is less complex than C++ and C# but as all programming languages, it does have its gotcha-moments. It's also Mac only so if you are targeting Windows or Linux it is not really an option.

There isn't much difference between Outlets/Actions and Signals/Slots and that's probably the reasons why I didn't have much problems when I was introduced to Cocoa Outlets/Actions (coming from a Qt background). So if you were working around them, you probably were doing something wrong..

As for IDEs, it largely depends on the OS I'm targeting, none of them are multitudes better than the others, they all get the job done, they all have their strengths and weaknesses (and problems), they all have GUI designers and they all work differently enough that no comparison between them makes much sense anyway ;). So what I use depends on the targeted OS of the software I'm writing:

Mac OS X only -> Cocoa with Xcode
Windows only -> Visual Studio (mostly .NET framework)
Cross platform -> QT with QtCreator (same dev platform on all targeted OS is a clear win in this case)

As for documentation, I find the Qt documentation the most readable and easiest to navigate... although I use google most of the time as my documentation ;)

Comment: Objective-C is ***not*** Mac-only. It can be used with any platform C can be used with.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to look at it. To hear the other side, I would say this makes for quite a good read:
http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2008/04/what-microsoft-could-learn-from-apple.ars

Personally I find one should also consider performance. Objective-C and the former Nextstep libraries seem a lot more compact while WPF is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: ???!!!! The linked article compares 25-year-old Microsoft technology (Win16/Win32) with the latest Apple technology in an attempt to argue that Apple's technology is better. In point of fact, 10-year-old Microsoft technology (WinForms) is comparable to the Apple's latest technology, and 5-year-old Microsoft technology (WPF) is simply light years ahead of it. The article's author was extremely deceptive in his treatment of the subject, and I question your judgment/motives in linking to such rubbish. See my answer for a detailed and objective comparison between WPF and Cocoa.

Comment: Yes, one should definitely consider performance. WPF and Cocoa have similar performance for most typical uses. WPF performs better when memory is tight or when portions of complex scenes change, or the changes are simple translations, rotations, fades, etc. Cocoa performs better when an entire scenes change in complex/nonlinear ways every frame. Cocoa's extremely limited feature set allows its libraries to be about 3MB smaller than WPF's, but Cocoa application code is necessarily much bigger than WPF application code (like 3x as big) which generally makes up the difference and then some.